# How to set the heights of the bootstrap dynamic panels?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

[image]
[image]

i am having the blocks of different heights and even the height cannot be predefined as they are completely dynamic blocks where the data depends!

and if we try to expand the blocks there will be some new information to be shown over there...

how to handle the heights of the these blocks???

dynamically

is there any suitable plugins for this in jquery?

Comment: Handle height in the sense ? You need all heights to be equal...right..? Can you put the HTML you had written to achieve this ?

Comment: And I would polish (format and grammar) the question.